# How can getElementById(idname) find the right element and yet element.id shows the id as "" and not as "idname"?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have searched and searched, but did not find a similar situation and answer.

I am able to access an element with getElementById(idname) and even have access to its value, however when I try to access its id it displays as "" instead of "idname". How is this possible?

Example:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("test").value); //is shown as Hello World
console.log(document.getElementById("test").id); //is shown as "" and not as "test"
```

Edit: I have found the answer see below.

Comment: It's weird. Do you have a `getElementById` function declared somewhere, or are you using `document.getElementById` and just didn't copy it here? What is the html of this "test" element?

Comment: What is `getElementById`? That function only exists on `document`, but not in the global scope.

Comment: I am using document.getElementById and will edit to reflect it more clearly!

Comment: kLabz, the html of this "test" is  a property of custom tag (which I have no access to) in a JSP file.

Comment: Can you post an example of this?  I can post an example of it not doing what you describe... https://jsfiddle.net/q2n9o8b0/1/

Comment: If it involves custom tags, the "id" field might indeed not work. Use `getAttribute()`

Comment: @Rajesh: Nope, that works with custom elements as well. You don't ___ever___ need to use `getAttribute` to get an `id` from a DOM element.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Elements found by `getElementById` ___always___ have an `id`, or they couldn't have been returned.

Comment: You've got something else wrong, somewhere else.  This is not your actual problem.

Comment: I have tried to replicate the issue with pure html and I am unable, hence why I am here. If the code was not sensitive I would gladly share it. What I can say is that I am able to get the element as described, which is a form, and its value, just not the id for some reason. The project runs on IE8 if that helps.

Comment: Apparently there are situations where getElementById works without having an id, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and found out why document.getElementById(idname) retrieves the element but not its id. Our testing browser is IE11 that runs in compatibility mode (the project was originally for IE8) and IE can fetch a name attribute with document.getElementById and thus the element is retrieved but has no id.

A simple example:

```
<input name = "test" value = "test value"></input>
<input id = "test2"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log("test id :" + document.getElementById("test").id);
console.log("test2 id :" + document.getElementById("test2").id);
console.log("test value :" + document.getElementById("test").value);
```

Results:

```
test id :
test2 id :test2
test value :test value
```

Comment: One more reason to drop support for IE8...

Comment: I agree with that, IE8 has been problematic to say the least.